# Error:org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Website is not mapped

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, web-services, maven

I am trying to create project with restful web services.I am getting an error

> org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Website is not
>   mapped

.I have tried each solution to solve this error.Please review my code and let me know if there is any suggestion.Thank You

GifController:

```
  package com.gif.code.controller;

  import java.util.List;

  import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
  import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
  import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
  import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
  import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
  import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

  import com.gif.code.model.GifModel;
  import com.gif.code.service.GifService;

  @RestController
  public class GifController {

    @Autowired
    GifService gifService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/getAllData", method = RequestMethod.GET,  headers = "Accept=application/json")
    public List<GifModel> getData() {
        System.out.println("In Controller");
        List<GifModel> listOfData = gifService.getAllData();
        return listOfData;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/getData/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET, headers = "Accept=application/json")
    public GifModel getDataById(@PathVariable int id) {
        return gifService.getData(id);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/addData", method = RequestMethod.POST, headers = "Accept=application/json")
    public void addData(@RequestBody GifModel gifModel) {   
        gifService.addData(gifModel);

    }

}
```

GifModel:

```
    package com.gif.code.model;

    import javax.persistence.Column;
    import javax.persistence.Entity;
    import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
    import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
    import javax.persistence.Id;
    import javax.persistence.Table;

    @Entity
    @Table(name="WEBSITE")
    public class GifModel {

    @Id
    @Column(name="id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    int id;

    @Column(name="title")
    String title;   

    @Column(name="description")
    String description;

    public GifModel() {
        super();
    }
    public GifModel(int i, String title,String description) {
        super();
        this.id = i;
        this.title = title;
        this.description=description;
    }
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }
    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }
    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }
    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }
}
```

GifService:

```
    package com.gif.code.service;


import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import com.gif.code.dao.GifDao;
import com.gif.code.model.GifModel;

@Service("gifService")
public class GifService {

    @Autowired
    GifDao gifDao;

    @Transactional
    public List<GifModel> getAllData() {
        System.out.println("In Service");
        return gifDao.getAllData();
    }

    @Transactional
    public GifModel getData(int id) {
        return gifDao.getData(id);
    }

    @Transactional
    public void addData(GifModel gifmodel) {
        gifDao.addData(gifmodel);
    }

}
```

GifDao:

```
package com.gif.code.dao;

import java.util.List;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.gif.code.model.GifModel;

@Repository
public class GifDao {

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sf) {
        this.sessionFactory = sf;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public List<GifModel> getAllData() {
        System.out.println("In Dao");
        Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        List<GifModel> textList = session.createQuery("from Website").list();
        return textList;
    }

    public GifModel getData(int id) {
        Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        GifModel gifmodel = (GifModel) session.load(GifModel.class, new Integer(id));
        return gifmodel;
    }

    public GifModel addData(GifModel gifmodel) {
        Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        session.persist(gifmodel);
        return gifmodel;
    }

}
```

Spring-servlet.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.0.xsd">

    <annotation-driven />

    <resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

    <beans:bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
        destroy-method="close">
        <beans:property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <beans:property name="url"
            value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/gifdata" />
        <beans:property name="username" value="root" />
        <beans:property name="password" value="Chirpn123" />
    </beans:bean>

    <!-- Hibernate 4 SessionFactory Bean definition -->
    <beans:bean id="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <beans:property name="annotatedClasses">
            <beans:list>
                <beans:value>com.gif.code.model.GifModel</beans:value>
            </beans:list>
        </beans:property>
        <beans:property name="hibernateProperties">
            <beans:props>
                <beans:prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
                </beans:prop>
                <beans:prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</beans:prop>
            </beans:props>
        </beans:property>
    </beans:bean>

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.gif.code" />

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

    <beans:bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <beans:property name="sessionFactory" ref="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory" />
    </beans:bean>


</beans:beans>
```

Pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.gif.code</groupId>
    <artifactId>Gif</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Gif Maven Webapp</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
           <version>3.1.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency> -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Hibernate -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Apache Commons DBCP -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Spring ORM -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- AspectJ -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
            <version>${org.aspectj-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.6</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <finalName>Gif</finalName>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${jdk.version}</source>
                    <target>${jdk.version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>

    </build>
    <properties>
        <spring.version>4.2.1.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <security.version>4.0.3.RELEASE</security.version>
        <jdk.version>1.7</jdk.version>
        <hibernate.version>4.3.5.Final</hibernate.version>
        <org.aspectj-version>1.7.4</org.aspectj-version>
    </properties>
</project>
```

Comment: Please add the complete stacktrace

Answer (score 9, accepted):

HQL works with the class names not with table names!

So you have to write:

```
List<GifModel> textList = session.createQuery("from GifModel").list();
```

Comment: Hello Jens, I have another error at the time post data.                              Error: org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: com.gif.code.model.GifModel

Comment: @user3386599 Looks like you have delete an Object but not the reference to it. Please create a new question with the code and the exception